# Docker bind mount is empty inside a containerized TeamCity build agent with DOCKER_IN_DOCKER enabled

Tags: docker, build, continuous-integration, teamcity

I'm running containerized build agents using the [`linux-sudo`](https://hub.docker.com/layers/jetbrains/teamcity-agent/2021.2.1-linux-sudo/images/sha256-19113d9103f0bff5f541c767d8c4c6eeb0f5174969c79a000cc2ed9e8d2cf7cb?context=explore) image tag and, using a [Dockerfile (here)](https://github.com/chrisobrien1/misc/blob/master/teamcity-agent/Dockerfile) I have successfully customized it to suit our needs. This is running very well and successfully running the builds I need it to.

I am running it in a Swarm cluster with a [docker-compose file (here)](https://github.com/chrisobrien1/misc/blob/master/teamcity-agent/docker-compose.yml), and I have recently enabled the `DOCKER_IN_DOCKER` variable. I can successfully run `docker run hello-world` in this container and I'm happy with the results. However I am having an issue running a small utility container inside the agent with a `bind mount` volume.

I want to use [this Dockerfile](https://github.com/chrisobrien1/misc/blob/master/teamcity-agent/util/Dockerfile) inside the build agent to run `npm` CLI commands against the files in a mounted directory. I'm using the following command to run the container with a custom command and a volume as a `bind mount`.

```
docker run -it -v $(pwd):/app {IMAGE_TAG} install
```

So in theory, running `npm install` against the local directory that is mounted in the container (`npm` is the command in the `ENTRYPOINT` so I can just pass `install` to the container for simplicity). I can run this on other environments (Ubuntu and WSL) and it works very well. However when I run it in the `linux-sudo` build agent image it doesn't seem to mount the directory properly. If I inspect the directory in the running utility container (the `npm` one), the /app folder is empty. Shouldn't I expect to see the contents of the bind mount here as I do in other environments?

I have inspected the container, and it confirms there is a volume created of type `bind` and I can also see it when I list out the docker volumes.

Is there something fundamental I am doing wrong here? I would really appreciate some help if possible please?

Comment: In a Docker-in-Docker context, `docker run -v` options refer to the nested Docker container's filesystem, not the host filesystem; confusion around which filesystem you're using is one of the good reasons to avoid DinD.  It sounds like you're trying to update host files, though, so you more likely want zero Docker daemons instead of two?  Or, in a CI context, do you want to `RUN npm ci` in a Dockerfile, without a volume mount at all?